# PL/SQL nested loop (loop within a loop)

Tags: oracle, plsql

Below is a PL/SQL I'm working on

```
declare
v_sql varchar2(500);
BEGIN
for t in (
    SELECT distinct ID 
    FROM TABLEB
    ) loop
    for c in (
        select * from (
            select 'delete from ' as test 
                from  dual
            union all
            select 'TABLEA'||' where ' as test 
                from dual
            union all
            select 'ID='||t.ID 
                from dual
            )
        ) loop
        v_sql := v_sql || c.test;
        end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
    end loop; 
END;
/
```

The result I'm getting is this

```
delete from TABLEA where ID=1
delete from TABLEA where ID=1delete from TABLEA where ID=2
```

I want

```
delete from TABLEA where ID=1
delete from TABLEA where ID=2
```

Any help on the PLSQL will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not clearing the buffer after you've printed the statement, so you're appending the next statement to the first one. To clear the buffer, add

```
v_sql := NULL;
```

after the line which reads

```
dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

What is the purpose of the inner FOR loop? It does nothing that requires a loop, and can be simply rewritten like this:

```
declare
  v_sql varchar2(500);
begin
  for t in (select distinct id from tableb) loop
    v_sql := 'delete from tablea where id = ' || t.id ||';';
    dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
  end loop; 
end;
/
```

BTW, it seems that you're missing the terminating semicolon in line `v_sql := ...`

Demonstration on HR's DEPARTMENTS table:

```
SQL> declare
  2    v_sql varchar2(500);
  3  begin
  4    for t in (select distinct department_id id from departments) loop
  5      v_sql := 'delete from tablea where id = ' || t.id ||';';
  6      dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
  7    end loop;
  8  end;
  9  /
delete from tablea where id = 10;
delete from tablea where id = 20;
delete from tablea where id = 30;
delete from tablea where id = 40;
delete from tablea where id = 50;
delete from tablea where id = 60;
<snip>
```